# Clojure Map with # literal

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between

```
#:user{:profile{:name "Sally Clojurian"
                     :address {:city "Austin" :state "TX"}}}
```

and

```
{:user {:profile {:name "Sally Clojurian"
                  :address {:city "Austin" :state "TX"}}}}
```

I know that for the last on if I want to get name I can just do :

```
(get-in [:profile :name] map)
```

How would I get name for the first map?

Comment: (get-in [:profile :name] map) doesn't work in getting the name. Did you mean ( get-in map [:user :profile :name] ) in the example above?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of printing a map beginning with `#:qualifer{ ... }` is an abbreviated form of printing when all of the keys of the map are keywords with the same qualifier, or namespace.  You can cause it to print without that abbreviation as shown below:

```
$ clojure
Clojure 1.10.1
user=> (def m1 #:user{:profile{:name "Sally Clojurian"
                     :address {:city "Austin" :state "TX"}}})
#'user/m1
user=> (pr m1)
#:user{:profile {:name "Sally Clojurian", :address {:city "Austin", :state "TX"}}}nil
user=> (doc *print-namespace-maps*)
-------------------------
clojure.core/*print-namespace-maps*
  *print-namespace-maps* controls whether the printer will print
  namespace map literal syntax. It defaults to false, but the REPL binds
  to true.
nil
user=> (binding [*print-namespace-maps* false] (pr m1))
{:user/profile {:name "Sally Clojurian", :address {:city "Austin", :state "TX"}}}nil
```

Answer (score 1):

If a map is def'ed as:

```
  (def myMap #:user{:profile{:name "Sally Clojurian"
                         :address {:city "Austin" :state "TX"}}})
```

than to get to `profile name` you can do something like :

```
(get-in map [:user/profile :name])
```

Comment: #:{} is the syntax for namespaced maps. It provides a default namespace for *keyword* keys in a map. Please refer to https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/ns-map. It will clarify if this information is put as a context before the example in the response above.